Find row in Matrix A which is closest two Matrix B
Lets say I have two matrices A and B given by
set.seed(123)
m1 = matrix(runif(10*5), nrow = 10, ncol = 5)
m2 = matrix(runif(10*5), nrow = 10, ncol = 5)

I want to find for each row in matrix A the row in matrix B which is closest to the row in matrix A. I know I can do this by looping over each row in A and comparing it to each row in B like this:
for(i in 1:nrow(m1)){
  dist = 9999
  index = -1
  for(j in 1:nrow(m2)){
    test = sqrt(sum(abs(m1[i,]-m2[j,])))
    
    if (test < dist) {
      dist = test
      index = j
    }
  }
  print(index)
}

I have however a million rows and it takes forever. I'm struggeling to find a efficient way. Any ideas?

Why take the square root?

I was contemplating L1- or L2-norm and did something inbetween...

Here is one base R solution using apply :
apply(m1, 1, \(x) which.min(sqrt(colSums(abs(x - t(m2)))))) 
#[1]  8  3  2  3  3  1  2  3  6 10

Comparing it with your current solution it fares well :
set.seed(123)
m1 = matrix(runif(10 * 5), nrow = 10, ncol = 5)
m2 = matrix(runif(10 * 5), nrow = 10, ncol = 5)

baseR_sol <- function(m1, m2) {
  apply(m1, 1, \(x) which.min(sqrt(colSums(abs(x - t(m2))))))  
}

for_loop_sol <- function(m1, m2) {
  for(i in 1:nrow(m1)){
    dist = 9999
    index = -1
    for(j in 1:nrow(m2)){
      test = sqrt(sum(abs(m1[i,]-m2[j,])))
      
      if (test < dist) {
        dist = test
        index = j
      }
    }
    print(index)
  }
}


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  baseR_sol = baseR_sol(m1, m2), 
  for_loop_sol = for_loop_sol(m1, m2), times = 10L
)

#         expr   min    lq    mean median     uq    max neval
#    baseR_sol 158.0 185.2  865.81 195.35  224.8 6902.8    10
# for_loop_sol 764.6 830.2 1051.29 973.45 1312.0 1348.9    10


One can try collapse::dapply(x, f, MARGIN = 1)  for faster apply

We can use dista from Rfast
library(Rfast)

apply(dista(m1, m2, type = "manhattan"), 1, which.min)
## [1]  8  3  2  3  3  1  2  3  6 10


Faster if one uses collapse::dapply instead.

great solution! added into the benchmark

Or rowMins(dista(m1, m2, type = "manhattan"))

A follow-up benchmark based on @Ronak Shah's solution
set.seed(123)
m1 <- matrix(runif(10 * 5), nrow = 10, ncol = 5)
m2 <- matrix(runif(10 * 5), nrow = 10, ncol = 5)

# Ronak Shah's original solution
f1 <- \() {
    apply(m1, 1, \(x) which.min(sqrt(colSums(abs(x - t(m2))))))
}

# a variant to Ronak Shah's solution, by removing `sqrt` and moving `t(m2)` out of `apply`
f2 <- \() {
    tm2 <- t(m2)
    apply(m1, 1, \(x) which.min(colSums(abs(x - tm2))))
}

# Friede's solution
f3 <- \() {
    tm2 <- t(m2)
    collapse::dapply(X = m1, FUN = \(x) which.min(Rfast::colsums((abs(x - tm2)))), MARGIN = 1L)
}

# G. Grothendieck's solution
f4 <- \(){
    apply(Rfast::dista(m1, m2, type = "manhattan"), 1, which.min)
}

# a variant to G. Grothendieck's solution, by using `dapply`
f5 <- \(){
    collapse::dapply(X = Rfast::dista(m1, m2, type = "manhattan"), which.min, MARGIN = 1)
}

# Onyambu's solution
Rcpp::cppFunction("IntegerVector closestRcpp(NumericMatrix A, NumericMatrix B) {
  int n = A.nrow();
  IntegerVector closest(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    double prev_dist = 1e308, dist;
    for (int j = 0; j < B.nrow(); ++j){
      double dist = sum(abs(A(i, _) - B(j, _)));
      if (dist < prev_dist) {
        prev_dist = dist;
        closest[i] = j+1;
      }
    }
  }
  return closest;
}")
f6 <- \() {
    closestRcpp(m1, m2)
}

# jblood94's solution
f7 <- \() as.integer(Rfast::knn(m1, 1:nrow(m2), m2, 1, "manhattan"))

microbenchmark(
    f1(),
    f2(),
    f3(),
    f4(),
    f5(),
    f6(),
    f7(),
    unit = "relative",
    check = "equivalent"
)

shows
Unit: relative
 expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq       max neval
 f1() 30.923077 28.758065 7.746297 30.333333 30.394737 2.2178388   100
 f2() 20.730769 20.096774 5.883996 22.227273 21.460526 2.1000075   100
 f3() 12.500000 12.370968 4.607372 13.030303 12.565789 2.5487359   100
 f4() 13.576923 13.387097 3.553832 13.969697 13.723684 0.9572675   100
 f5()  9.846154  9.919355 2.830048 10.242424 10.289474 0.9190842   100
 f6()  1.000000  1.000000 1.000000  1.000000  1.000000 1.0000000   100
 f7()  3.230769  3.370968 1.636883  3.575758  3.539474 1.1243941   100


Maybe f3  = \() { tm2 = t(m2); collapse::dapply(X=m1, FUN=\(x) which.min(Rfast::colsums((abs(x - tm2)))), MARGIN=1L) }

@Friede thanks for you contribution! added to the benchmark

Thanks so much, for the interesting benchmark!

Could you also add the Rcpp written below into the output?

@Onyambu see the update

Consider using Rcpp/C:
Rcpp::cppFunction("IntegerVector closestRcpp(NumericMatrix A, NumericMatrix B) {
  int n = A.nrow();
  IntegerVector closest(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    double prev_dist = 1e308, dist;
    for (int j = 0; j < B.nrow(); ++j){
      double dist = sum(abs(A(i, _) - B(j, _)));
      if (dist < prev_dist) {
        prev_dist = dist;
        closest[i] = j+1;
      }
    } 
  }
  return closest;
}")

closestRcpp(m1, m2)
[1]  8  3  2  3  3  1  2  3  6 10


Using Rfast::knn
library(Rfast)

as.integer(knn(m1, 1:nrow(m2), m2, 1, "manhattan"))
#>  [1]  8  3  2  3  3  1  2  3  6 10


short and efficient code, +1! Added into benchmark, see the update
